# How to get SQL Server process ID with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On my Windows Server 2008 I have local instance of SQL Server 2008 (or later 2012.) The server also has IIS configured to run ASP.NET web applications that connect to that SQL server to do basic SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE operations.

I also have a Windows service application that I wrote in C# that runs on the same server. I want to add a function to it that checks CPU usage on the SQL Server process. I can do so knowing its PID.

My question is, how to get the process ID of the SQL Server process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('processid'),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
```

you can check in Task Manager as follow

[image]

Comment: That is a very cool way to find out a PID. Thanks. I checked, it worked on my local SQL Server installation. Just curious, what would happen if SQL Server is not installed on the same machine?

Comment: from the above query, you can get the PID of the remotely connected sql server, but if sql server is not installed on your
local machine, than you will not see the PID of the remotely connected sql server in processes of task manager on local machine

Comment: @Sagarpatel: Thanks. Also just discovered that doing `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName');` will return the machine name that I can compare to `Environment.MachineName` from C#.

Comment: @Sagarpatel: I will. I need to test it out in my actual code first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of PID just use [Process.GetProcessesByName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, but how would I know the process name?

Comment: It is sqlservr.exe. BTW did you look at this article: http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2011/01/04/find-the-sql-server-instance-name-using-task-manager/

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks. Just curious, why would there be more than a single sqlservr.exe running at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostics;   //at the top of your class


Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Hopefully that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

To get the process ids of SQL Server instances in C#

```
var ProcessId = Process.GetProcesses()
                        .Where(P => P.ProcessName == "sqlservr")
                        .Select(P => P.Id);
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault is not the best option in this case. There could be more instances of sql server on machine

Comment: Yeah that's true. I ll modify my answer. Thanks.